# Module not found: Can't resolve in ./src/screens/HomeScreen.js

Tags: reactjs

```
Hi I have a problem in Frontend/src/screens/HomeScreen.js which say Module not found: Can't resolve 
Thanks, everybody
```

Here is My debug log
{
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'creat-react-app'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.5
3 info using node@v12.18.2
4 verbose npm-session 1b8cf5f7e2ec9261
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/creat-react-app 221ms
8 http fetch GET 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/creat-react-app 95ms
9 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for creat-react-app@latest 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/creat-react-app - Not found
10 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 1ms
11 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 2681ms
12 verbose stack Error: 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/creat-react-app - Not found
12 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-fetch\check-response.js:104:15
12 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
13 verbose statusCode 404
14 verbose pkgid creat-react-app@latest
15 verbose cwd D:\Soft Develope\3-React.js\TR-Basir-Faranesh\11-Node\Amazona\Frontend
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19041
17 verbose argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "creat-react-app"
18 verbose node v12.18.2
19 verbose npm  v6.14.5
20 error code E404
21 error 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/creat-react-app - Not found
22 error 404
23 error 404 'creat-react-app@latest' is not in the npm registry.
24 error 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
25 error 404 Note that you can also install from a
26 error 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
27 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in the `packages.json`. It's `create-react-app`, not `creat-react-app`

Comment: Thanks - I reinstall create-react-app and now there is another error "Module not found: Recursion in resolving"

Answer (score 0):

**I think you didn't import a module that is used used by some function.**

just try to find the function and click **"ctrl + space"** it will auto-import into your document.